# bash split array into separate files with dynamic name

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, bash, jq

I have the following returned to me as a response of a mocking tool I'm using.

```
{
  "mappings" : [ 
{
"id" : "bcf3559f-7ff7-406b-a4f1-6d3e9ac00e63",
"name" : "Hellow world 2",
"request" : {
  "url" : "/hello-world-2",
  "method" : "POST"
},
"response" : {
  "status" : 200,
  "body" : "\nBody content for stub 3\n\n",
  "headers" : { }
},
"uuid" : "bcf3559f-7ff7-406b-a4f1-6d3e9ac00e63",
"persistent" : true,
"priority" : 5
  }, 
{
"id" : "9086b24f-4f5e-465a-bbe5-73bbfb82cd5c",
"name": "Hello world",
"request" : {
  "url" : "/hello-world",
  "method" : "ANY"
},
"response" : {
  "status" : 200,
  "body" : "Hi!"
},
"uuid" : "9086b24f-4f5e-465a-bbe5-73bbfb82cd5c"
} ]
}
```

I'd like to know how I can split each object into it's own file with the file named after the id of the object.

E.g:

bcf3559f-7ff7-406b-a4f1-6d3e9ac00e63.json

bcf3559f-7ff7-406b-a4f1-6d3e9ac00e63.json

I have got as far as this so far but can't get it over the line:

```
jq -c '.mappings = (.mappings[] | [.])' mappings.json |
  while read -r json ; do
  N=$((N+1))
  jq . <<< "$json"  > "tmp/file${N}.json"
done
```

Comment: what all the file's are supposed to have?, kindly share a sample for one id

Comment: A language with its own JSON library would be more appropriate for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend printing the id on one line, and the corresponding object on the next. For example:

```
jq -c '.mappings[] | .id, .' mappings.json |
    while read -r id ; do
    echo "id=$id"
    read -r json
      jq . <<< "$json"  > "tmp/${id}.json"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple Python script instead (or the equivalent in your favorite, general-purpose programming language).

```
import sys, json

d = json.load(sys.stdin):
for o in d['mappings']:
    with open(os.path.join('tmp', o['id'] + '.json'), 'w') as f:
        json.dump(o, f)
```

This would be more efficient and less error-prone, at least until `jq` gets some sort of `output` built-in:

```
# hypothetical
jq '.mappings[] | output("tmp/\(.id).json")' mappings.json
```